# Getting first element of series from pandas .value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For some reason this is not working for a specific variable:

```
print(metadata[variable].value_counts(dropna=False)[0])
```

To get the number of counts of the most common category. Gives the error:

```
AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4730, in get_value
        return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
      File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
      File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
      File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
      File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
      File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
    KeyError: 0
```

It works when I ask for the second most common, using index [1], etc.
And this only happens for this variable, works fine for all the other columns in the dataframe metadata.
If I ask for the entire value_counts this is the output:

```
 print(metadata[variable].value_counts(dropna=False))
    3    532
    1    252
    2    178
    4    146
    5    112
    Name: variable1, dtype: int64
```

Is it because dtype is int64?

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: `metadata[variable].value_counts(dropna=False).iloc[0]`

Comment: That works, why does it not always need iloc?

Comment: sounds like `mode`?

Comment: @Agustin the linked duplicate answers your question with examples :) `[0]` doesnot work since there is no key(index) as `0`  returned by value_counts

Comment: `[1]` works not because it is returning the second most frequent, but because the index of value `1` is coincidentally the second most frequent. Try `[3]` for example. I'll bet it returns `532`. `iloc` is more robust as it does what you mean, i.e. give you the positional index rather than the named index.